# Android AWS RekognitionClient error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to use Amazon Web Services Recognition in Android but I get a Problem with the RekognitionClient. As I try to initialize it, I get the error:

> No instance field endpointPrefix of type Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/amazonaws/services/rekognition/AmazonRekognitionClient; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient' appears in /data/app/com.amazonaws.husebnerbot-2/base.apk)

I have tried everything but I can not find my error. Can you help me?

```
private void initializeRekognitionSDK() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Rekognition Client");

    CognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.identity_id_test),
            Regions.fromName("us-east-1")
    );

    amazonRekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of AWS Android SDK are you using? can you use the ` public AmazonRekognitionClient(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider,
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)` constructor and see if the behavior changes?

Comment: Hello and Thanks for your answer. I am using the sdk version 2.4.5. 
Do you have an example for the constructor?

`ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
  clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
amazonRekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider, clientConfiguration);`

Like this?

Comment: Tried it like in the last comment and it still gets me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working amazon image rekognition I have faced the same issue and I have resolved by adding the library, to be frank, don't understand how adding new library resolved the issue. Here is the library which I have added

`compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper', version: '2.6.13'`

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper', version: '2.6.13'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    implementation files('JarFilePath/AmazonRekognition/lib/aws-android-sdk-rekognition-2.6.9.jar')
}
```

Here is the final code which works to recognize the image using Amazon Rekognition

```
  ByteBuffer imageBytes = null;
    try {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))) {
            imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(MainActivity.this,
            "YOUR IDENTITY POOL ID",
            Regions.EU_WEST_1);
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);

    AmazonRekognitionClient rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider, clientConfiguration);
    rekognitionClient.setEndpoint("https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    rekognitionClient.setSignerRegionOverride("us-east-1");

    DetectLabelsRequest request = new DetectLabelsRequest()
            .withImage(new Image()
                    .withBytes(imageBytes))
            .withMaxLabels(10)
            .withMinConfidence(77F);


    DetectLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectLabels(request);
    List<Label> labels = result.getLabels();
    System.out.println("REUSKT   " + result.toString());

    System.out.println("Detected labels for " + photo);
    for (Label label : labels) {
        System.out.println(label.getName() + ": " + label.getConfidence().toString());
    }
```